# Migrating to Azure SQL backend - packets.go:36 - connection reset by peer

Tags: azure-sql-database, grafana

Asking here as well as grafana github on the off chance this is a generic issue.

We recently had a requirement to move away from MariaDB and I am trying to migrate grafana to use azure sql backend.

```
Grafana 7.1 
OS CentOS 7
Azure sql database (cloud)
```

I can connect from my virtual machine to the database using telnet

Telnet from client to database

```
Trying 10.xx.xxx.xxx...1433
Connected to myhostname.database.windows.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I changed the setting in grafana.ini to pass the connection string as a URL and conn_max_lifetime to be less than "30"

```
# Use either URL or the previous fields to configure the database
# Example: mysql://user:secret@host:port/database

url = mysql://user:password@myhostname.database.windows.net:1433/dbname

# For "postgres" only, either "disable", "require" or "verify-full"
ssl_mode = false

;ca_cert_path =
;client_key_path =
;client_cert_path =
;server_cert_name =

# For "sqlite3" only, path relative to data_path setting
;path = grafana.db

# Max idle conn setting default is 2
max_idle_conn = 0

# Max conn setting default is 0 (mean not set)
max_open_conn = 0

# Connection Max Lifetime default is 14400 (means 14400 seconds or 4 hours)
conn_max_lifetime = 2

# Set to true to log the sql calls and execution times.
log_queries = true
sudo systemctl start grafana-server.service
```

Startup logs

```
Sep 06 20:18:44 grafana7-1005086944-2-1009631108 grafana-server[8755]: [mysql] 2020/09/06 20:18:44 packets.go:36: read tcp 10.xx.xxx.xxx:42552->10.xx.xxx.xxx:1433: read: connection reset by peer
Sep 06 20:18:49 grafana7-1005086944-2-1009631108 grafana-server[8755]: [mysql] 2020/09/06 20:18:49 packets.go:36: read tcp 10.xx.xxx.xxx:42562->10.xx.xxx.xxx:1433: read: connection reset by peer
Sep 06 20:18:55 grafana7-1005086944-2-1009631108 grafana-server[8755]: [mysql] 2020/09/06 20:18:55 packets.go:36: read tcp 10.xx.xxx.xxx:42566->10.xx.xxx.xxx:1433: read: connection reset by peer
Sep 06 20:18:55 grafana7-1005086944-2-1009631108 grafana-server[8755]: t=2020-09-06T20:18:55+0000 lvl=info msg="[SQL] SELECT `TABLE_NAME` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`=? and `TABLE_NAME`=? []interface {}{\"crcgr
Sep 06 20:18:55 grafana7-1005086944-2-1009631108 grafana-server[8755]: t=2020-09-06T20:18:55+0000 lvl=eror msg="Server shutdown" logger=server reason="Service init failed: Migration failed err: driver: bad connection"

packets.go:36
```

Ive tried switching the max_idle_conn, max_open_conn, conn_max_lifetime to different values but I still cant get a connection to work. Can anyone give me any pointers on what I should be doing?

I can see from azure that possibly a different driver is used but not sure what to do with this

```
// Go connection Sample Code:
package main
import (
    github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb
    database/sql
    context
    log
    fmt
    errors
)
```

Comment: It seems that  we cannot store Grafana  server settings in Azure sql : https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#database

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?